# React routes param auto decode string

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi does react router params automatically decodes string?

For example i have this route

```
<Route path="/callback/:url"/>
```

and when I call it with `C5jb20%3D`

it will print `C5jb20=` when I console.log() that parameters

Is this an expected behavior? Can I change this behavior so that I still get the encoded string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C5jb20%3D` is a URL encoded string, which is a way to encode special characters in a URL. For example, if you have a URL parameter like `?redirect=/some/path`, a server could interpret the forward slashes as routing paths, and mess up the expected routing. That's why you see things like `?redirect=%2Fsome%2Fpath`, and your example, in URLs.

`window.location.path` will have the original, unencoded URL.

You could also get it back with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
encodeURIComponent('C5jb20=') // "C5jb20%3D"
```

You probably don't want to, though, depending on your use case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! So, is this the expected behavior from react router? because If it is, then I will not decode the parameter after I extract it from params.. I just don't want to have unexpected error related to this encoded string :) Once again, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is expected and desired behavior.

Comment: Problem is, it's now common to replace space with a character (+ or -) in urls, and if there's one of this in the text, it'll be impossible to tell them apart. E.g. `iphone7%2B+seller` will be automatically converted to `iphone7++seller` in routeParams. If the auto-decoding can be disabled, this can be solved.

Comment: In my case, I actually need to get the encoded (original) param, is there anyway to get it from router without parsing windows.location.path?