# decode url before location change in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hey guys can you help me solve next issue? For example we have url like `site.com/post?comments=1,2,3,4` after I paste it in browser address string, my app opens and url decodes to `site.com/post?comments=1%2C2%2C3%2C4`, how to get rid of `%2C` in url and save it in original way and vice versa if someone opens url like `site.com/post?comments=1%2C2%2C3%2C4` decode it to `site.com/post?comments=1,2,3,4`? I know that I can use method lice `decodeURIComponent`, but I don't know where and in which moment exactly apply it. I'm using react and react-router. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React routes param auto decode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622153/react-routes-param-auto-decode-string)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/decodeURIComponent) for decoding and [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/encodeURIComponent) and encoding. To see the result run the snippet below:

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent(`site.com/post?comments=1%2C2%2C3%2C4`));
console.log(encodeURIComponent(`site.com/post?comments=1,2,3,4`));
```

Comment: I edited my question. I know how to decode it, but i don't know when exactly I should do it to see decoded url in browser

Answer (score 0):

The %2 that you see is due to the "," in your URL, for encoding and decoding you can use the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64

```
var base64 = require('base-64');
var bytes = site.com/post?comments=1,2,3,4
var encoded = base64.encode(bytes);
console.log(encoded);
```